# Ruby implementations written in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

There are many and many implementations of Ruby programming language.

Are there any Ruby implementations written in Ruby (bootstrapped)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [**Rubinius**](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius) is it.

> Rubinius is a modern language platform that supports a number of programming languages.
>
> Many popular Ruby applications, like Rails, run on Rubinius, which aims to be compatible with Ruby version 2.2.